# Sitecore Treelist validation for items with a layout

Tags: validation, sitecore, sitecore7.2, treelist

I'm trying to find a way to have the selectable items in a treelist to be items **with** a layout.
Since items **without** a layout **are not visible**, it must be impossible to select these.
Do i have to write a custom validation? If yes, how can i check if an item has a layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict a treelist selection to specific templates, which should allow you to achieve this without customization (Assuming you can be sure that only items based certain templates will have layout).

You need to use `IncludeTemplatesForSelection` in the Treelist's datasource.

This blog post explains further
http://getfishtank.ca/blog/treelist-data-source-hidden-functionality

Comment: Hi martin, 
Yes, i know about those, but, since the website isn't finished, and i don't know which templates will be added in the future, i think it's not a good practice to add the templates into the datasource. What i'm trying to do is make sure that every item selected, has a layout, which makes sure the item can be seen. New items & new templates should be visible after that too.

Comment: Don't add specific templates to `IncludeTemplatesForSelection` parameter. Just create a template called `Template with layout` or `Page template` and remember to inherit from it every time you have a template which is used for items with layouts. And then as Martin explained.

Comment: Good tIp. I didn't realise this setting works with inherited templates too.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I used this and it worked without a problem!